# SEPM embedded database stuck on "Starting"

Tags: embedded, symantec-endpoint-protection

I have recently upgraded SEPM (Symantec endpoint protection manager) from 12.1.4 to 12.1.5.
Upgrade completed successfully however the 'Symantec Embedded database' service stuck on 'Starting' status.
Tried everything alone and with Symantec support. Eventually they gave up and I had to create new fresh VM and install new SEPM.
After installation and configuration, the SEPM behaved properly for 2 days, on the 3rd day i tried to login to the console and it failed again. the 'Symantec Embedded database' service was the same - stuck on 'Starting'.

Did anyone experience such behavior with SEPM 12.1.5?

Thank you.

Roee.

Answer (score 1):

Finally had to re-install again the VM, with specific user right assignment for the DB.